# Can't Properly "connect" a class with its objects

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to make a class that would be the template of a "custom widget" for a "game" I'm trying to make. The problem is that I can only get it to work if when I call the class, I specify the Frame object that holds everything together. I've been searching my whole afternoon and couldn't find a concrete answer...

The following code works but instead of just needing to write `StatusButton().grid()` I have to use `StatusButton().frame.grid()`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

class StatusButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(StatusButton, self).__init__()
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx = 10, pady = 10, bd= 5, relief = RAISED)
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text = "Hunger Bar")
        self.pgbar = Progressbar(self.frame)
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text = "Eat")
        self.label.pack()
        self.pgbar.pack()
        self.button.pack(pady = 5, ipadx = 15)
        return

root = Tk()   
buttonslist = [StatusButton(root) for x in range(16)]

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(4):
        StatusButton(root).frame.grid(row = r, column = c)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm guessing I'm not properly "conecting" the frame object to the class, even though the former is inside the latter, because when the previous code gets executed, but with `StatusButton().grid()` instead, the TKinter window pops up normally, but without any content, like if i was "gridding" an empty Frame object. How can I fix this, so that when `StatusButton().grid()` is run, my "custom widget thing" appears?

Sorry if this is a noob error, it's my first week in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't taking advantage of your subclass.  You initialize `Frame` with no arguments and then create a new one with arguments.  You then create widgets with `self.frame` as a parent instead of `self`.  Change it to this:

```
class StatusButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(StatusButton, self).__init__(master, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5, relief=RAISED)
        self.label = Label(self, text="Hunger Bar")
        self.pgbar = Progressbar(self)
        self.button = Button(self, text="Eat")
        self.label.pack()
        self.pgbar.pack()
        self.button.pack(pady=5, ipadx=15)
```